# Build failing on TFS 2012 msbuild

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

We have recently migrated our **TFS Server from 2010 to TFS 2012 Server**, upgraded out build controllers to it.

When we try to TFS Build to create an msi with wix, solution failed with following errors.

One solution with 102 projects with Libraries and Services built correctly and the other solution which has web application had issue like.

CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file '\bin\Release\foo.dll' could not be found \WebApplication.csproj

CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file '\bin\Release\foo2.dll' could not be found \WebApplication.csproj

CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file '\bin\Release\foo3.dll' could not be found \WebApplication.csproj

CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file '\bin\Release\foo4.dll' could not be found \WebApplication.csproj

CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file '\bin\Release\foo5.dll' could not be found \WebApplication.csproj

Comment: Is that all the errors? normally that would suggest the foo.dll etc projects aren't building and the next project that is trying to build can't reference them.

Comment: I have done work around given in the link [“Project Dependencies” of Visual Studio 2008 broken in MSBuild](http://victorsergienko.com/project-dependencies-of-visual-studio-2008-broken-in-msbuild/) to get rid of the errors it worked for certain solutions, but still some projects have this build errors.. Can anyone had this erros